# Where to instantiate TextToSpeech class?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using **TextToSpeech** class of android but when I `instantiate` it inside a method `TTS doesnt work` but if I declared it within `onCreate()` method it works.
(Note that my app runs in both cases)

Why is it so ?

> I have heard that it is a good practice to instantiate classes within
>   methods if no other methods are using it.

**Updated:**

**Code:**

```
  TextToSpeech t1;

 public void speak(View v){
        Log.i(TAG,"speak method");
        t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });


        t1.speak("I m speaking out dude",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
```

Comment: maybe show us something from your code?

Comment: Don't *link* to your code. **Include** your code in the question. The link may not be available in a year, but code will be here as long as SO is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After creating the instance of TextToSpeech**, it Initializes text-to-speech engine. This is an asynchronous operation. The OnInitListener (second argument) is called after initialization completes. The status can be either TextToSpeech.SUCCESS or TextToSpeech.ERROR based on the initialization status.

As it is an asynchronous, it takes some time to complete its operation.

**So, here is the answer**,

When you create the instance at onCreate, the engine gets time to initialize before you call "speak(String str)" and it works. But when you create the instance inside the method itself, TTS engine does not get time to complete its initialization before Speak.