# How to use a TTS instance in multiple fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have a MainActivity that just hosts the Navigation Component, all the functionality resides in other fragments and I need to use TTS in all of them.

Do I declare a single `TextToSpeech` instance and pass it around to each fragment (how and where?), or is it better for each of them to have its own instance? I'm already more inclined on choosing the second one but you never know.

---

**Edit: this indecision comes from the need of managing the TTS handle according to the activity or fragment lifecycle.**

If I initialize a different TTS field in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` for each fragment, then I would also need to call `TextToSpeech#shutdown()` in the fragments' `onDestroyView()`. It might be the easiest way but I'm concerned about the constant creation and destruction of TTS instances every time the user goes to another fragment.

The alternative would be to initialize the TTS field in my activity's `onCreate()` and to shut it down in the activity's `onDestroy()`, but then how would I pass the handle to the fragments while using the Navigation Component? By using [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) or a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)?

Comment: Please see this solution which is nicely explained.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206477/where-to-instantiate-texttospeech-class

Comment: Thanks but I think my question has a different scope. Please refer to the edit I've made.

Comment: One could argue that it could live in a `ViewModel` which is shared between the fragments and shutdown in `onCleared` but I'd be interested in other ideas as well